# Module loading order

Tags: angular

AppModule:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CoreModule } from '@core/core.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { LayoutModule } from '@layout/layout.module';
import { ViewsModule } from '@views/views.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    LayoutModule,
    ViewsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Interested in SharedModule and LayoutModule

The SharedModule has a pipe which I use in the LayoutModule. Pipe is export in SharedModule. But I get an error in Layout: Error: The pipe 'faIcon' could not be found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modules imported into your AppModule don't communicate with each other. They only provide features to your AppModule. If you use a component from LayoutModule into your AppComponent, its context only depends from your LayoutModule : it won't pick features coming from imports of your AppModule.

If some component from your LayoutModule needs to use your pipe, you need to import SharedModule into LayoutModule.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the pipe in the app.module.ts file and add it to the declarations.

Comment: I want to define global algorithms in one module and import them together into the main module. Then to use it throughout the application. How can I best do this? How can I make sure that I have imported SharedModule before importing others?

Comment: How large is your app? I get the feeling, you are using way to much custom modules here for your usecase. And more help can only be givin, if you make more of your code visible.

Comment: You can look at [github](https://github.com/MACTEPwar/ScaledAngularArchitecture/tree/master/src/app)